# Give 404 status on accessing the nginx server with the IP, but not with domain

Tags: nginx

I got the following servers in Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    server_name _;
    return 404;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl ;
    server_name _;
    return 404;
}

server {
    server_name sub.domain.com 192.168.2.10;
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sub.domain.com 192.168.2.10;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }

}
```

What I want to achieve with this is to give a 404 error when Nginx is accessed with the external IP, on HTTP port 80 and HTTPS port 443. But allow access when it is accessed with sub.domain.com or my local IP. It did work fine when I added "default_server" to the last server block, it would give an 404 on my external IP but only on HTTP, on HTTPS it would still go through and show the content. What am I doing wrong, I have no idea.

With the code block above for nginx, it used the third server block to redirect me to the HTTPS url. But that page just won't show up, I get a white page.

Update:

I now tried this config as suggested by Mark

```
server {
    listen 1.2.3.4:80;
    listen 1.2.3.4:443;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}

server {
    server_name sub.domain.com 192.168.2.10;
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sub.domain.com 192.168.2.10;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }

}
```

But I can still access my Nginx server with the external ip. e.g: `http://1.2.3.4` and `https://1.2.3.4` 1.2.3.4 is ofcourse my external IP on my server. For demo purposes it's removed here.

Update 2:

Addding `default_server` to the listens of the first block as sugested by Mark still does the same thing as explained in the first update.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with help of https://security.stackexchange.com/a/107918

Where the return 444 for the SSL has a certificate with fake information, so the real domain can't be found in the certificate.

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    return 444;
}

server {
    server_name sub.domain.com 192.168.2.10;
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sub.domain.com 192.168.2.10;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is your [`listen`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) directives.

You want some `server` blocks to listen only the the external IP

```
# Replace 1.2.3.4 with your external IP
server {
    listen 1.2.3.4:80;
    listen 1.2.3.4:443;
    server_name _;
    return 404;
}
```

I'm not sure you want the "ssl" modifier on your listen directive for port 443, because the block is not set up with an SSL directive.

The `server` blocks you want to respond to both the subdomain and internal IP may be fine, because I presume the subdomain resolves to the external IP, so you want those `server` blocks to listen on both the external and internal IP addresses.

Also, consider returning `444` instead of `404`. This is an Nginx-specific response code which simply drops the connections, providing the best performance and spending the minimal resources on these unwanted requests.

Comment: I have now this, http://pastebin.com/UktjzMYC . But it's still not working as expected? 1.2.3.4/1.2.3.4.149 is ofcourse my external IP, changed it because I am publishing this online. The subdomain does indeed resolve to the external IP. With this config, I can acces the Nginx server with my external IP on both HTTP and HTTPS just fine.

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on "not working as expected". Provide specific examples of requests you make, the response you received and the response you expected.  Consider updating your question.

Comment: The solution you provided I would expect that accessing `http://1.2.3.4/` and `https://1.2.3.4/` would not work. But it still does.

Comment: Not sure. Try adding `default_server` to both `listen` directives in the block I suggested.

Comment: Could it have to do with this? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55790/nginx-how-to-prevent-processing-requests-with-undefined-server-names-with-http